# Show or add the name of each polygon shapefile to its attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have converted rasters to polygons. Each of them have 3 fields in their attribute table:  id=0, fid=0, shape=polygon zm.  How can I add name of each polygon to attribute table?

Comment: What is this "name" and where is it coming from? Edit your question to include examples of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi all my tiffs have names for example abad,tif  then i convert it to polygon its name is abad.shp

Comment: When i merged all of them i cant get name of polygon with "i" tools in arcmap so i need to have the field name in attribute table for every polygon

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record the raster dataset name (e.g. abad) that the polygons were converted from you need to follow these steps for each of your polygon datasets:

1. Run the Add Field tool to add a new text field, call it `datasetname`.
2. Run the Calculate Field tool and calculate into your new text field `datasetname` the name of the raster dataset.
3. Repeat steps 1 & 2 for every polygon dataset.
4. Now run the merge tool to bring all the datasets into a single dataset.

In your question you give no indication as to how many polygon datasets you have, *in any question you should always indicate the volume of data you are dealing with as this dictates the solution*.  If just a few, then do this manually. If you have thousands then a very simple model with a FeatureClass iterator will automate all this.

Comment: Hi first of all i appereciate your help  i want to know how can i assign  datasetname  to rasterdaset name in calculate field  ?  is it correct  ?rasterdataset="rasterdataset name"

Comment: I think i know how to perform this action for all rasters  but first  i must know what syntax use for assigning this two item : 1-dataset nane  and 2-name of the raster data set                       you know i am not very familier with cods  in  calculate field  tool

Comment: You have still not indicated how polygon datasets you are wanting to process? So if it is hundreds then the modelbuilder route is best. You would be using an iterator and you can pass the dataset name into the field calculate tool using inline variable substitution. Read the help file on iterators and inline variable substitution you will see many examples.

Comment: Hi please see this link (this question with image) i have tried what you said https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429750/adding-name-of-each-shapefile-polygon-to-its-attribute-table-with-add-field-usin/429753#429753