# Adding name of each shapefile polygon to its attribute table with add field using ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes, error-000229

[image]I have converted raster files(tif) to polygons. Each of them has 3 fields in its attribute table: id=0, fid=0, shape=polygon zm. How can I add the name of each polygon to the attribute table? As you can see in the picture I added a field (txt)and then used the field calculator but I received this error :

```
Executing (Iterate Rasters): IterateRasters C:\Users\???\Desktop\n # # NOT_RECURSIVE
Start Time: Tue Apr 26 02:18:57 2022
Succeeded at Tue Apr 26 02:18:58 2022 (Elapsed Time: 0.07 seconds)
Executing (Raster Domain): RasterDomain C:\Users\???\Desktop\n\mnm.tif C:\Users\???\Desktop\n\2\mnm.tif.shp POLYGON
Start Time: Tue Apr 26 02:18:58 2022
Succeeded at Tue Apr 26 02:18:58 2022 (Elapsed Time: 0.14 seconds)
Executing (Add Field): AddField C:\Users\???\Desktop\n\2\mnm.tif.shp fm TEXT # # 25 # NULLABLE NON_REQUIRED #
Start Time: Tue Apr 26 02:18:58 2022
ERROR 000229: Cannot open C:\Users\???\Desktop\n\2\mnm.tif.shp
Failed to execute (Add Field).
Failed at Tue Apr 26 02:18:58 2022 (Elapsed Time: 0.01 seconds)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your shapefile needs to be named differently. Since your model is failing on Add Field, I tested Add Field on a shapefile named test.tif.shp and it returned an error. I suggest trying to rename it without the other period. ex) test.shp

Comment: You can use [Parse path](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/parse-path.htm) for this

Comment: @BERA is correct, feed the iterator output (mnm.tif) into the parse path tool to return just the name (mnm) and then use its output as inline variable substitution. Also make its output a precondition to the Ratster Domain tool to ensure correct order of operations.

Comment: hi again i did what you said and use parse path it is useful   .now i faced with an error but i think maybe  it is about names of my files(raster) because some of my raster names have space .the error is like what i attached .

Comment: Start by not naming a folder 10.2.1401

Comment: hi again both of you are awesome i think finally i will finish it thank you so much  at the end of process-final step- i faced  with an error in "calculate field" :the calculated value is invalid for the row with object id=0 .......  as you know i put name1 for field name and expression= value and expression type= vb but  :General error executing calculator.
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Expected end of statement
Failed to execute (Calculate Field).

Comment: @coral What is the value you are trying to field calculate and what is the field type?

Comment: Hi value is the name of my raster file after parse path (name) for example mnm.tif is  mnm  and i need to add  field  for each shape file with name of polygon or raster file( value) so it is txt format

Comment: Hi I finished it. thank you so much . I found my mistake in expression. I appreciate your help.

Comment: sorry I do not know how can I add reputation in this forum? How to close thread or post and mark it as solved thread?